# How to sort answers to question?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, answers, sort

If I retrieve a question like so:

http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.8/questions/1429951&sort=votes

I expect the answers to be sorted by votes, but they're not.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the `sort=votes` parameter is for when you are retrieving multiple questions in one API call, such as with this URL - the questions in the response are ordered by vote.

http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.8/questions/1429951;2383701;619895?sort=votes&type=jsontext

In terms of how you could sort the responses - you do have the up + the down vote count from which you could sort on your application side, or you could make another request to the api with the extracted answer IDs and `sort=votes`, which is really a waste of resources when you already have all the data.

Comment: Hmmm... I never thought of sorting on the application side. I'll look into that.

Comment: @George - OR you could take the `questions/{id}/answers` route and specify `sort`.  `sort` on `/questions/{id}` applies to the question(s) returned.  `{id}` is vectorized in both cases (in all cases, infact).

Comment: @Kevin: Oh, okay. I just thought it was wasteful to fetch the question and then all the answers. I guess it won't hurt if the first request has `body=false` set.

Comment: @George - /questions/{id} only gives you the first "page" of answers anyway.  If its the full set of answers (by `answer_count`) you **should** do the sort locally.  Otherwise a second request is necessary anyway, might as well have the sorting done on our end.